# how to graph 3 3D plot next to each other

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

how I can graph 3D graph with the following code next to each other? subplot dosen't work like a 2D plt.plot()

```
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
f0 = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
ax.scatter3D(X,Y ,Z,facecolor="yellow")
```

I want to use this code to print 3 graphs next to each other horizantaly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a starting point:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.mgrid[-2:2:50j, -2:2:50j]
z = np.cos(x**2 + y**2)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"}, figsize=(10, 5))
axs[0].plot_surface(x, y, z)
axs[1].plot_wireframe(x, y, z, rstride=3, cstride=3)
axs[2].plot_surface(x, y, z, alpha=0.25)
axs[2].plot_wireframe(x, y, z, rstride=3, cstride=3, color="k", lw=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]